# NPE after !=null

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

I'm using an Accessibility Service and I'm facing a very strange `NPE`.

Inside the `onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event)` method I have this code.

```
if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED 
       && event.getSource() != null) {
            AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();

            if (waiting && source.isEditable()) {
                .....

            }else if (!waiting && source.isEditable()) {
               .....
            }
```

The crash reports I'm receiving say that `isEditable()` is being performed on a null pointer even though I checked that it's not null. Unfortunately this does not happen on any of my devices. <s>And another strange thing is that the NP is only in the `else if`, the `if` is checked without any problems.</s>

This was my previos code

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED 
       && source != null) {....
```

I was advised by a friend to switch to the first code (check then assign), but it still didn't help

Thanks for any help in advance.

**Edit:** `waiting` is `false` most of the time,I think that is way the `NPE` is mostly thrown from the `else if`

**Edit 2:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.isEditable()' on a null object reference
  at  com.dhm47.nativeclipboard.AccesService.onAccessibilityEvent(AccesService.java:184)
  at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$1.onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityService.java:659)
  at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$IAccessibilityServiceClientWrapper.executeMessage(AccessibilityService.java:752)
  at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:37)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

The `isEditable()` is a part of Android see [isEditable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html#isEditable())

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace?

Comment: Something *else* is null then, apparently..

Comment: Look at the code inside `isEditable`. NPE might come from there. --- And the `if` doesn't call `isEditable` if `waiting` is false, so that's why the `if` doesn't fail.

Comment: Also, just for good measure, try calling `getSource()` only once, i.e. `Object object = event.getSource()`, then `&& object != null` and then `... source = object`

Comment: Calling `getSource()` once was my original code yet it had this same problem. But I'll change it back if it might help.

Comment: 2 successive calls to `getSource()` are not guaranteed to yield the same output. your friend gave you a bad piece of advice. (change it back).

Comment: I'll change it back, but how can that happen if the `event` is the same?

Comment: Can you retrieve device info along with the crash report? I wonder if it's poorly implemented firmware (i.e. Samsung).

Comment: I wish it was (not my first issue with Samsung), but the report has been sent from different devices (Moto, Nexus,Samsung,LG and Sony)

Comment: I suggest you to set breakpoint in that line, and try to debug it. Only two explanations which i have for your case is, something on other thread wipe your source, or you are not running this code (happened to me once, i kept old version of code, and when i did changes, i change old code instead new one)

Comment: What do you mean by "or you are not running this code"?

Comment: @DHM47 build issue which cause you to run older version, or like i had my situation where i hac copy of entire class somewhere else, and i applied changes to wrong class. my suggestion is go back to your original version where you set source before condition, and then log at each step what is source and is it null. and of course try to debug it, it will be better, it shows ou exactly what happening